# Form validation in jQuery without using plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, alert

I want to perform client-side validation of a simple form using jQuery, but I can't use any plugins for validation.  I want to display any error messages in  a single alert box.

This is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="a">
    Name : <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
    Address : <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" /> <br/>
    Email: <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br/>

    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

If a user submits the form without filling any inputs then I need to display 3 error messages in single alert box. Like this

```
Name can not be empty.
Address can not be empty.
email can not be empty.
```

If only one or two fields remain empty, then I need to control error message according the situation.

Here I tried it using jQuery. But the alerts display in separate boxes:

My jQuery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    valid = true;   
    if ($('#name').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your name");
        valid = false;
    }

    if ($('#address').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your address");
         valid = false;
    }    
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/14/).

Can anybody tell me how can I figure this out?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loop through each input element in the form, and check if it has a value. If not append the error message to a string which you later alert out if valid is false.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var valid = true,
        message = '';

    $('form input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if(!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if(!valid) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/17/

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. One question, can I display an error if the email is not valid?

Comment: i copied ninja code and updated with email pattern check here: http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/22/  courtesy @ninja :)

Answer (score 4):

try following:

```
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var valid = true,
    errorMessage = "";

    if ($('#name').val() == '') {
       errorMessage  = "please enter your name \n";
       valid = false;
    }

    if ($('#address').val() == '') {
       errorMessage += "please enter your address\n";
       valid = false;
    }    

    if ($('#email').val() == '') {
       errorMessage += "please enter your email\n";
       valid = false;
    } 

    if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
       alert(errorMessage);
    }   
  });
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/24/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want 1 alert to appear at a time you need to check the state of `valid` for each condition:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    valid = true;   

    if (valid && $('#name').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your name");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (valid && $('#address').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your address");
         valid = false;
    }    

    return valid;
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/16/)

Comment: thank for quick response. Using this code I can get only one error messsage.

Answer (score 1):

**form validation:**

This code is provided for the simple form validation using jquery.you can use this for validation in your form.

Thanks

```
        <form action="" method="post" name="ContactForm" id="ContactForm1">
        <div id='message_post'></div>
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *">
         </div>
         <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         <input type="text"  name="lname" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *">
        </div>
         <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         <input type="text"  name="phone" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone (bh) *">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         <input type="text"  name="email" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *">
         </div>
         <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         <textarea rows="5"  name="message" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group form-buttons">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" id="btn" name="buttn" value="Send Message"  class="btn btn-default"/><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
        </span>
        </div>
        </form>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>

// just for the demos, avoids form submit

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#ContactForm1" ).validate({
  rules: {
            fname: "required",
            lname: "required",
            phone: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            message: "required",

  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code might be ok if the OP wanted to use a plugin but the OP did not want to use a plugin!