# Form Validation using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a validation form like so:

```
<form id="registerform" method="post" onsubmit=return checkformdata();>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value=""/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="1"/>
</form>
```

`checkformdata()` Validates only the first name and last name for the checkbox field, which is done using jQuery.
Here is the code that I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  jQuery('#registerform').submit(function() {
    if (!jQuery("#privacy").is(":checked")) {
      alert("none checked");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

It is also working but the alert field is comes twice for example firstname is empty then alert for first name and alert for checkbox comes up. I want to show the alert for the checkbox after the *checkformdata();* function. Is it possible to give the priority first for javascript then the jquery validation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is that jQuery code the contents of `checkformdata()` ?

Comment: You attached two different handlers to the submit event. It will run twice. Why don't you validate everything in the same place?

Comment: I am using some other theme in wordpress. I saw that function checkformdata() is 20 to 25 files are there i didn't find out that validation code in the theme file(hard to find) so i decide this way using the firebug i checked that form id and checkbox id by this i am doing using jquery through plugin.(Not editing theme file)

Comment: @vicky: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211128/form-validation-in-jquery-without-using-plugin/18211372#18211372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have one functions, which is the second method you are using. Both functions are called now, which is not wat you want. Also, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery`.

**Dont use return false!** Unless you know what you are doing.  Use preventDefault():

```
$('#registerform').submit(function(event) {
    var errorString = [];
    // START VALIDATION
    if ($("#privacy").is(":checked") ) {
        errorString.push("none checked"); // Save for later
    }
    if ($('[name="fname"]').val).length===0) {
        errorString.push("No firstname"); // Save for later
    }
    if ($('[name="lname"]').val).length===0) {
        errorString.push("No lastname"); // Save for later
    }

    // CHECK IF ERRORS ARE FOUND
    if( errorString.length !==0){
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the submitting
        // Do whatever you like with the string, for example;
        alert( "Something went wrong: \n"+errorString.join("\n") ); // alert with newlines 
    }
    // NO ERRORS FOUND, DO SOMETHING
    else{
        // all good. Do stuff now
    }

});
```