# How to validate tinymce text editor using jquery validation?

Tags: jquery

I am using Tinymce text editor for text editor option in php.I plan to enable client side validation all fields are validated except tinymce editor(textarea).

Comment: What's your progress?

Answer (score 0):

I think, we no need to consider Tinymce separately for validation, because it will update corresponding textarea whenever you update its content. You need to validate that textarea normally how you are validating other controls.

[form validation in jquery without using plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211128/form-validation-in-jquery-without-using-plugin)